# Enforcing keyword-only arguments in decorated functions

Tags: python, decorator, functools

I have a class with several methods that require a certain argument be present, but for different reasons.

Typically, the argument will be attached to the instance as an attribute, in which case there is no need for the argument to be passed. However, if the attribute was missing (or `None`) this argument could be optionally passed as a keyword-only argument:

```
import functools

class Foo:
    def __init__(self, this_kwarg_default=None):
        self.default = this_kwarg_default
    
    @staticmethod
    def require_this_kwarg(reason):
        def enforced(func):
            @functools.wraps(func)
            def wrapped(self, *args, this_kwarg=None, **kwargs):
                if this_kwarg is None:
                    this_kwarg = self.default
                if this_kwarg is None:
                    raise TypeError(f'You need to pass this kwarg, {reason}!')
                return func(self, *args, this_kwarg=this_kwarg, **kwargs)
        
            return wrapped
        return enforced

    require_this_kwarg = require_this_kwarg.__func__

    @require_this_kwarg('because I said so')
    def foo(self, this_kwarg=None):
        print(f'This kwarg is {str(this_kwarg)}')
```

Mostly, this gives the desired behavior.

```
>>> myfoo = Foo(42)
>>> myfoo.foo()
This kwarg is 42
>>> myfoo.foo(this_kwarg=4)
This kwarg is 4
>>> yourfoo = Foo()
>>> yourfoo.foo()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "dec.py", line 15, in wrapped
    raise TypeError(f'You need to pass this kwarg, {reason}!')
TypeError: You need to pass this kwarg, because I said so!
```

But if any positional argument is passed, I get some unexpected behavior:

```
>>> myfoo.foo(4)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "dec.py", line 16, in wrapped
    return func(self, *args, this_kwarg=this_kwarg, **kwargs)
TypeError: foo() got multiple values for argument 'this_kwarg'
```

It would make sense, then to define `Foo.foo` to take `this_kwarg` as a keyword-only argument:

```
@require_this_kwarg('because I said so')
def foo(self, *, this_kwarg=None):
    print(f'This kwarg is {str(this_kwarg)}')
```

However...

```
>>> myfoo.foo(4)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "dec.py", line 16, in wrapped
    return func(self, *args, this_kwarg=this_kwarg, **kwargs)
TypeError: foo() takes 1 positional argument but 2 positional arguments (and 1 keyword-only argument) were given
```

In this case, the desired behavior would be to raise `TypeError: foo() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given`, just as would be expected if no decorator were used.

My hope was that `functools.wraps` would enforce the call signature of the decorated function. Obviously, though, this is not what `wraps` does. Is there some way to achieve this?

Comment: Am I correct when I say that you're looking to write a decorator that effectively does this: "check that the function decorated with this is always called in such a way that the `this_kwarg` parameter gets a value, and assign the default if the passed value is None"? And that you want the decorator to work regardless of whether the function is called with a keyword argument or a positional argument to assign that value?

Comment: @Grismar you are almost correct. It is not important to me whether `this_kwarg` is passed as a positional argument or a keyword argument (either would be fine, but I had originally envisioned it as a keyword argument — its not immediately obvious to me how it would work with a positional argument). What is important is that it the decorator works regardless of the call signature of the decorated function, e.g. maybe I have `def foo(*args, this_kwarg=None, **kwargs): ...` and `def bar(this_arg, this_kwarg=None, that_kwarg=5): ...` and both would be decorated in the same way

Comment: Put error aside, when ```self.default``` is not ```None``` and you passed in a positional argument, what should be printed? Your original function only accept two arguments, one for self and the other is keyword argument. When you calling the function, you passed in too many arguments of course Python will give you an error screen.

Comment: @HenryTjhia if only a single positional argument was passed, I suppose it would make sense to use this variable as `this_kwarg`; but if a positional argument were supplied along with `this_kwarg` as a keyword argument, this should raise a `TypeError` — just like if you tried to pass a positional argument to any other function that does not accept positional arguments in its call signature.

Comment: @corvus Well, ```self``` is counted as posonly arg.

Comment: @HenryTjhia good point. All the same I think it's pretty clear how we should expect a function with call signature `foo(self, this_kwarg=None)` to behave: `self.foo()` and `self.foo(this_kwarg=value)` are valid, but clearly `self.foo(extra_arg, this_kwarg=value)` is not. (We may also consider `self.foo(value)`, which is of course valid, but if `this_kwarg` is given positionally I am unsure how, in general, we could avoid it becoming mixed in with `args`). All I am looking for is a way to enforce these same kinds of constraints on a decorated function with an arbitrary call signature.

Comment: In short, the hope is that arguments should be handled exactly as they would be if the function were not decorated — but, with the caveat that this should work regardless of what the function's call signature actually is.

Comment: Does `def foo(self, *, this_kwarg=None):` not do what you want? If it's just the error message that's wrong by your expectation, be aware that *"takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given"* would not be the expected error message, because `self` is a positional argument.

Comment: Also, why u bother ``staticmethod`` and ``.__func__``? It works if you remove both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow, that was way trickier than I expected. I'd be interested to see if someone comes up with a simpler and cleaner solution, but I think this does what you need?

```
from inspect import getfullargspec
import functools


class Foo:
    def __init__(self, x_default):
        self.default = x_default

    @staticmethod
    def require_x(reason):
        def enforced(func):
            @functools.wraps(func)
            def wrapped(self, *args, **kwargs):
                argspec = getfullargspec(func)
                while True:
                    if 'x' in kwargs:
                        # it's explicitly there, so it will have a value
                        if kwargs['x'] is None:
                            kwargs['x'] = self.default
                        break
                    elif argspec.varargs is None:
                        # there are no varargs to eat up positional arguments
                        if 'x' in argspec.args[:len(args)+1]:
                            # x will get a value from args, offset by one for self
                            if args[argspec.args.index('x') - 1] is None:
                                args = tuple(a if n != argspec.args.index('x') - 1 else self.default
                                             for n, a in enumerate(args))
                            break
                        elif argspec.defaults is not None and 'x' in argspec.args[-len(argspec.defaults):]:
                            # x will get a value from a default
                            if argspec.defaults[argspec.args[-len(argspec.defaults):].index('x')] is None:
                                kwargs['x'] = self.default
                            break
                    elif 'x' in argspec.kwonlydefaults:
                        if argspec.kwonlydefaults['x'] is None:
                            kwargs['x'] = self.default
                        break
                    raise TypeError(f'{func.__name__} needs a value for x, {reason}.')

                func(self, *args, **kwargs)

            return wrapped

        return enforced

    require_x = require_x.__func__
```

I don't like production code that needs `inspect` to work, so I'm still dubious of whether you really need code that does this - there is probably a bit of an anti-pattern in the broader design here. But anything can be done, I suppose.

Comment: Amazing — I had to tweak it a little to get the exact behavior I was looking for, but this is pretty much it. `There is probably a bit of an anti-pattern in the broader design here.` Yes, I think you are right. Initially I thought a decorator could be an elegant solution for my needs, but after experimenting with it I realized that was probably not the case. If this is the only way to do it, then I think definitely not. Ultimately, my question was motivated more by curiosity than anything....

Comment: Unless someone else has a better idea, I will stick with the strategy I posted below, which doesn't answer the question in general but works nicely for my use case and is probably the 'pythonic' way to go

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't really answer the question; but it is a workable solution, illustrates the desired behavior, and is much too long for a comment anyway.

Maybe this is a bad/stupid idea. I'm not sure.

What I want is basically an optional keyword argument:

```
def foo(self, this_kwarg=None):
    if this_kwarg is None:
        this_kwarg = self.default
    ...
```

But what if `self.default is None`? In general, this should be allowed. However, certain methods such as `Foo.foo` require that this `this_kwarg` is not `None`, i.e. they will fail if it is. So basically I am looking for descriptive/informative error handling in a nice 'pythonic' way.

One way around it is to implement `Foo.foo` like this:

```
def foo(self, this_kwarg=None):
    if this_kwarg is None:
        this_kwarg = self.default
    if this_kwarg is None:
        raise TypeError('This kwarg cannot be `None`, because I said so!')
    ...
```

But then I have to add this code to every method that has this requirement. (Suppose I have several other methods `Foo.bar`, `Foo.baz` etc., that all cannot work if the argument is `None`.)

I thought a decorator would be an elegant & pythonic way to implement this without lots of repetitive code. The problem is that `Foo.foo`, `Foo.bar`, `Foo.baz`, etc. all have different call signatures. Besides `this_kwarg`, some of these methods may have 1 or more (maybe an arbitrary number) of positional and/or keyword arguments.

Maybe, then, the best solution is this:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, default=None):
        self.default = default
    
    def require_this_kwarg(self, this_kwarg, reason):
        if this_kwarg is None:
            this_kwarg = self.default
        if this_kwarg is None:
            raise TypeError(f'This kwarg cannot be `None`, because {reason}!')
        return this_kwarg

    def foo(self, *args, this_kwarg=None, **kwargs):
        this_kwarg = self.require_this_kwarg(this_kwarg, 'I said so')
        ...
```

This was actually my original solution. Then I tried to do it with a decorator & ran into the issue I described. I thought the question of whether function call signatures can be enforced inside a decorator was an interesting one.

Answer (score 0):

After read your question and comments, my understanding about your question is you are searching value in following order.

1. If `this_kwarg` exist, use it.
2. If #1 failed, use `self.default`.
3. If #2 failed, raise error.

This code should work in either position or keyword argument.

```
import functools

class Foo:
    def __init__(self, this_kwarg_default=None):
        self.default = this_kwarg_default
    
    @staticmethod
    def require_this_kwarg(reason):
        def enforced(func):
            @functools.wraps(func)
            def wrapped(self, this_kwarg=None):
                def _process(k=self.default):
                    if k is None:
                        raise TypeError(f'You need to pass this kwarg, {reason}!')
                    return func(self, k)
                if this_kwarg is None:
                    return _process()
                return _process(this_kwarg)
            return wrapped
        return enforced

    require_this_kwarg = require_this_kwarg.__func__

    @require_this_kwarg('because I said so')
    def foo(self, this_kwarg=None):
        print(f'This kwarg is {str(this_kwarg)}')
```

The core logic is in code below

```
                    ...
 12                 def _process(k=self.default):
 13                     if k is None:
 14                         raise TypeError(f'You need to pass this kwarg, {reason}!')
 15                     return func(self, k)
 16                 if this_kwarg is None:
 17                     return _process()
 18                 return _process(this_kwarg)
                    ...
```

Code logic matches searching order mentioned above:

1. If `this_kwarg` isn't None, return `func(this_kwarg)`. (line 18)
2. If `this_kwarg` is None, try return `func(self.default)`. (line 17)
3. If both `this_kwarg` and `self.default` are None, raise error. (line 14)

**Test**

```
import pytest

@pytest.mark.parametrize("default_val", [None, 1, "this_kwarg_default=1"])
@pytest.mark.parametrize("call_val", [None, 3, "this_kwarg=3"])
def test_foo(default_val, call_val):
    print("parametr are: ", default_val, call_val)
    f = eval(f"Foo({default_val})")
    eval(f"f.foo({call_val})")
```

**Output:**

```
============================================================================== test session starts ===============================================================================
platform darwin -- Python 3.8.5, pytest-6.1.2, py-1.9.0, pluggy-0.13.1
rootdir: /Users/kz2249/tmp/st/tests
collected 9 items                                                                                                                                                                

test_example.py parametr are:  None None
Fparametr are:  1 None
This kwarg is 1

.parametr are:  this_kwarg_default=1 None
This kwarg is 1

.parametr are:  None 3
This kwarg is 3

.parametr are:  1 3
This kwarg is 3

.parametr are:  this_kwarg_default=1 3
This kwarg is 3

.parametr are:  None this_kwarg=3
This kwarg is 3

.parametr are:  1 this_kwarg=3
This kwarg is 3

.parametr are:  this_kwarg_default=1 this_kwarg=3
This kwarg is 3

.

==================================================================================== FAILURES ====================================================================================
______________________________________________________________________________ test_foo[None-None] _______________________________________________________________________________

default_val = None, call_val = None

    @pytest.mark.parametrize("default_val", [None, 1, "this_kwarg_default=1"])
    @pytest.mark.parametrize("call_val", [None, 3, "this_kwarg=3"])
    def test_foo(default_val, call_val):
        print("parametr are: ", default_val, call_val)
        f = eval(f"Foo({default_val})")
>       eval(f"f.foo({call_val})")

test_example.py:36: 
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 
<string>:1: in <module>
    ???
test_example.py:19: in wrapped
    return wrap()
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 

k = None

    def wrap(k=self.default):
        if k is None:
>           raise TypeError(f'You need to pass this kwarg, {reason}!')
E           TypeError: You need to pass this kwarg, because I said so!

test_example.py:16: TypeError
============================================================================ short test summary info =============================================================================
FAILED test_example.py::test_foo[None-None] - TypeError: You need to pass this kwarg, because I said so!
========================================================================== 1 failed, 8 passed in 0.10s ===========================================================================
```